# How is this Javascript doing padding to the right?

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript and I'm trying to figure out exactly what it's doing:

```
str = str + Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(padch);
```

*Note: I know that `str` is the string we are working with, `len` is the length of that string we are working with, `padch` is the character we want to pad with. I'm not sure what `Array` and `join` are doing here.

Comment: Execute it and enjoy debugging it.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `new` in from of that `Array()`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla No, [you can call it as a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-constructor) as well: _"When Array is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it also creates and initializes a new Array object. Thus the function call Array(…) is equivalent to the object creation expression new Array(…) with the same arguments."_

Comment: `Array` create an array with lenght equals to the number of padding needed, then the `join` function build a string that is the string sum of all elements separated by `padch` character, that is the padding string you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the interesting part:

```
Array(len + 1 - str.length).join(padch);
```

It uses this syntax:

```
Array(10); // creates an array with 10 undefined values
```

Then you join it together, with the padcharacter.

```
Array(10).join(","); // gives 9 comma's (9 because 10-1)
```

Then `len + 1 - str.length` is the math to generate the correct amount of padding characters.

Comment: If `len = str.length` like he said, having `len + 1 - str.length` seems unnecessary, because that would mean the same as `str.length + 1 - str.length`, which is 1.

Comment: @Piwwoli `len` is the target length with padding, not the length of `str`.  The OP could be a little clearer here.

Comment: Important note worth to mention is that the **`join()` ignores `undefined`** elements in array.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks Halcyon. I get it now.